# GCU + Cassandra using 'Click to deploy'

Tags: java, cassandra, google-compute-engine, dropwizard, datastax

I create a Cassandra cluster using 'Click to Deploy feature. So far so good. Also , I create an extra machine where my app is installed.

When I logged in into the cassandra cluster I'm able to use cqlsh to the query the schema...but I'm not able to connect my app to the cluster.

I'm using Java with Datastax driver + dropwizard+ dropwizard-cassandra(https://github.com/stuartgunter/dropwizard-cassandra).

My java connection configuration is the following:

```
cassandraFactory:
  clusterName: "test-c"
  keyspace: "test"
  contactPoints: ["ip-nodeA"]
  port: 9041
#  protocolVersion: "V2"
#  compression: "LZ4"
#  metricsEnabled: false
#  jmxEnabled: false
#  shutdownGracePeriod: "10 seconds"
```

Cassandra is listening in

```
tcp        0      0 *:9160                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:9042                  *:*                     LISTEN
```

Should I open some port to foreign address or something like this ?I think this should be the issue

Thanks,
Ignacio

Comment: Sorry, I fix it. I just add a rule in the firewall to open the port for the specific source. You can do it from the google compute engine console